# Run sh script from docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I build a docker image with bellow Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.4

ADD setENV.sh /usr/local/bin/setENV.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/setENV.sh

CMD [ "/bin/bash" "usr/local/bin/setENV.sh" ]
```

The setENV script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "PORT=${PORT:-1234}" >> .env
echo "PORT_SERVICE=${PORT_SERVICE:-8888}" > .env
echo "HOST_SERVICE=${HOST_SERVICE:-1234}" > .env
```

I build the image as:

```
docker image build -t my-node .
```

And then I run the image as:

```
docker run -it my-node bash
```

But the script is not executed. 
From inside the container a run the script as:

```
/bin/bash usr/local/bin/setENV.sh
```

And working fine.

Note that I am using docker for windows.

Comment: You seem to be missing a leading slash on the `CMD` path. Unless docker runs from root directory that won't work.

Comment: Also I tried /usr/local/bin/setENV.sh but it still does not work

Comment: From the question title, you seem to be confusing `sh` with `bash`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
docker run -it my-node bash
```

just runs `bash`.

To run the `CMD`, you have to do

```
docker run -it my-node
```

However, note that your container will immediately exit because there is nothing to do after writing to the file. So to see the result, you would need to add `cat .env` or something to `setENV.sh`.

Comment: A doubt @Robin, the file created with the script inside container is created as .env? instead of .env. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is some invisible character in your script file.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I created the file in windows and the EOL were in windows format. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the last line should be

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "usr/local/bin/setENV.sh" ]
```

You missed a `,`.